# SqlDataReader Convert Int to Int?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I need to return a NULL or Blank value for Apvl_Lvl_Id if the SQL result returns NULL as the integration this passes the Apvl_Lvl_Id value to can't handle a value if it doesn't match an existing value for that instance.

I can't figure out what I'm missing, hoping someone can offer some pointers. Hope the below code is enough for an example.

```
   while (dr.Read())
      {
        if(dr.IsDBNull(Apvl_Lvl_Id))
         {
           int? Apvl_Lvl_IdNULL;
           Apvl_Lvl_Id = Apvl_Lvl_IdNULL;
         }
         else
         {
            Apvl_Lvl_Id = dr.GetInt32(0);
         }
      }
```

Comment: @Christian.K Some background; I'm getting the Apvl_Lvl_Id based on a system ID. The value returned is then passed to another class that builds a txt file which is then run by an integration. IF there is no value for the Apvl_Lvl_Id the SQL returns NULL, so I need to not pass a value to the class building the file otherwise it breaks the integration. Is this possible? From what you've said I can kinda see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but that code makes little sense. Apparently, `Apvl_Lvl_Id` is supposed to be the [column ordinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.7.2) - effectively the zero-based count of the column in a row - that you check for being DBNull. Then you are trying to assign the actual column's value to that ordinal? Apart from that, there is just no way you can assign `null` to an `int`. Introduce a separate variable, say, `Apvl_Lvl_Value`, make it an `Nullable<int>` (or `int?`) and assign the the column's value as required (actual value or `null`).

In "short", the code should more like this:

```
  while (dr.Read())
  {
     int? Apvl_Lvl_Value;
     // Check if the value of the column with the ordinal Apvl_Lvl_Id is DBNull
     if(dr.IsDBNull(Apvl_Lvl_Id))
     {
       // If so, use .NET "null" for the rest of the logic.
       Apvl_Lvl_Value = null;
     }
     else
     {
        // Use the actual columns (non-NULL) value.
        Apvl_Lvl_Value = dr.GetInt32(Apvl_Lvl_Id);
     }

     // Do something with the column's value, stored in Apvl_Lvl_Value

  }
```

Now, some things here are guesswork which are not really clear otherwise from your question, but generally, the above is a "pattern" by which one would use `IsDBNull()` and
a `Get*()` method together.

Answer (score 1):

And why don't you just set

```
Apvl_lvl_Id = null;
```

Comment: I can't convert Apvl_lvl_Id to null because it's an int, I need it as an int for when a value is returned. I only need it to be converted to a nullable int when a null value or 0 is returned.

Comment: @WHoward As long as you don't change the type of `Apvi_Lvl_Id` to `int?` there is no chance that `Apvi_Lvl_Id` will ever be null.